# Calling ToString("YYYY-mm-dd") results in wrong date format

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I've got a constructor which takes a `DateTime` object:

```
public Report(DateTime date, string start = "0", string end = "0")
{
    Logger.Info("Creating a new Report...");

    StartTime = start;
    EndTime = end;
    Date = date.ToString("YYYY-mm-dd");

    SetStartEndTimes();

    Logger.Info("Report Created");
}
```

Now, this was working fine just 3 days ago. However, I come back today, after a break, and this is the results I'm seeing:

[image]

As you can see, the date being passed in is right. However, after the format, it is not. Again, this worked before my break. I come back, and I get this. Am I missing something? Why would it format so incorrectly after working since the beginning?

**EDIT**

Thanks guys. The messed up part is looking through the source control at previous versions, this worked. Or maybe I imagined it working. I don't know. But it's been this way for about 3 months.

Comment: Lower case "m" stands for minute, not month! Uppercase "Y" should be lowercase "y".

Comment: YYYY isn't valid for the year.  It's yyyy And the mm is *minutes* so you're showing 49 above. Make that MM.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Year must be lowercase and month uppercase:

```
Date = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");  // btw, lowercase mm means minutes
```

[**Custom Date and Time Format Strings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: @Tim Are you referring to the fact that the variable isn't named? I hardly think that is worth a downvote.

Comment: @JohnWillemse it is fine, the line by itself would be incorrect, but `Date` is declared as a property. The syntax highlighting makes it seem like the `Date` type instead of a `Date` property. Either way the question was answered.

Comment: @NickFreeman Yes, I agree. I didn't understand the downvote, but it's gone now.

Comment: +1 Both answers were good, but I gave the check to the one who answered first.

Comment: @TimSchmelter that's what I was going to say, but thats how stackoverflow works. You can put an incorrect answer to get in first and then edit it to be correct and people will prefer your answer ;)

Answer (score 8):

This:

```
Date = date.ToString("YYYY-mm-dd");
```

Should be this:

```
Date = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Lowercase `mm` will give you minutes.

Comment: this will result in `YYYY-02-19` or similar

Comment: @JohnWillemse Not anymore!

Comment: Yes, they still are :P but you answer is great now ;)