# TryParseExact returns false when the string seems to match the pattern

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I have this format string `"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`

I have this date: `"2013-08-28 15:01:17"`

And this is my code:

`DateTime.TryParseExact(fromString, dateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out outDateTime);`

However it returns false indicating it failed to parse.

I'm not really sure why, any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16106435/352101

Comment: Note that the case is important on format strings. For example `MM` means month whereas `mm` are the minutes. Or `HH` means 24h clock and `hh` 12h clock(required if you provide an AM/PM designator).

Answer (score 6):

`YYYY` is not a valid format specifier (it would be parsed as a literal `YYYY`). Use lowercase `y`'s in your format string instead:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

**Further Reading**

- [The "yyyy" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#yyyySpecifier)

Comment: Damnit! I was just typing 'all my other parsing uses upper case...' then I checked and I am an idiot. Much appreciated, was tearing my hair out. Always the small things...

Comment: @SLC It happens to the best of us. Glad I could help.